# Many to Many relationship in Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I had 1:N relation in Room which look like this (typical Owner:List relation):

```
class NewsFeedAndPersonItem {
    @Embedded
    lateinit var newsFeedItem: NewsFeedItem
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "userId", entityColumn = "id"
    )
    var listOfPersons: List<Person> = listOf()

    fun getPerson() = listOfPersons.firstOrNull()

    fun getAvatar() = getPerson()?.photoSmallLink

    fun isPost() = newsFeedItem.type == 2

    fun NewsFeedAndPerson() {}

    fun NewsFeedAndPerson(newsFeedItem: NewsFeedItem, person: List<Person>) {
        this.newsFeedItem = newsFeedItem
        this.listOfPersons = person
    }
}
```

NewsfeedItem:

```
@Entity
@TypeConverters(NewsFeedTypeConverters::class)
class NewsFeedItem(

    // Common
    @PrimaryKey @Json(name = ParserConst.DEFAULT_ID) var id: Int = 0,

    @Json(name = ParserConst.USER_ID) var userId: Int = 0,

    @Json(name = ParserConst.CREATED_AT) var createdAt: String? = null,

    @Json(name = ParserConst.NEWS_FEED_TYPE) var type: Int? = null,

)
```

Person:

```
@Entity
data class Person(

    @PrimaryKey var id: Int = 0,

    var favourite: Boolean = false,

    var online: Boolean = false,

)
```

So far so good. The problem is that I need to change NewsFeed userId:String parameter to list of userIds (List)

My question is if it is still possible to solve via @Relation or if there is any simple alternative way how to achieve this.

Comment: You'll need a separate join entity to represent the relationship. You should be able to use `@Relation` with it, if you wish.

Comment: OK, could you please show me how this entity should look like?

Comment: [Here is a join entity](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/blob/v0.11/General/RoomMN/stuff/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/room/dao/Customer.java#L61-L88) joining a `Customer` and a `Category`. I happened to implement it as a `static` class, though that is not required.

Answer (score 0):

A many-to-many relationship is solved by creating a new table "in between" the two existing tables and creating two 1:N relationships to the newly created table.

Example: 
A Person can own many cars and a Car can be owned by many persons. To solve this many-to-many relationship you can create an Owner table which contain a FK reference to the Person PK and a FK reference to the Car PK.

If you also create a composite primary key out of these two foreign keys you also ensure that there can't be any duplicate ownerships in your database.